# Storing sensitive configuration data in memory

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, configuration

I am currently working on a new .net-core API and trying to settle on a way to access secrets/sensitive information that will be needed for everything to work smoothly.

Currently I am creating a new configuration provider/source that will reach out to our vault server (using hashicorp vault) to grab all configuration data needed including: connection strings, and private key's for web tokens.

This seemed like a good idea as I remove all sensitive information from config files like appsettings.json. however this would lead to the data being stored in memory as plain text which is a bit worrisome to me.

I considered re-encrypting the data before putting into the config dictionary, but I would still need to have the decrypt key...so I feel like it is the same issue with an additional step.

Is this just a case of overthinking things? Or should I reconsider having this data in configuration and make repeated calls to the vault for the data when needed?

Comment: Most likely yes, which is why the docs now advise against using [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-2.2#remarks) and there's even a [compatibility warning](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) about it. No matter what you do at *some* point the secret will be clear text. If someone can attach a debugger to your app and read its memory, you're toast already.

Comment: The source code for the [Azure Key Vault Configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is available on [Gtihub](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Configuration/Config.AzureKeyVault). You can check how they handle this situation, both in the docs and the source code itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not even think to look at the Azure Key Vault implementation for guidance, but I did just as you suggested and it seems that it is implemented like how I was going about it (though they were much more elegant). So yeah, this a case of overthinking, storing in memory as plain text is probably the best place for it. If they have access to server and can get to the memory, well I do have much bigger problems.

Comment: You can check the [data protection APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2) too. It does a different job - protecting data locally, but it could be useful as an add-on